# Prevent deadlock in SQL using query wait option

Tags: sql-server, database, database-deadlocks

We are using Amazon RDS for DB hosting. Recently we have seen occasional deadlocks. We tried to resolve it using `@@LOCK_TIMEOUT` but later found out that its only for the session not at database level.

I found this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms175463(v=sql.110)

which says you can set the query wait at the database level and set a expiry time. But there is a section which says it's not recommended

[image]

Can someone please guide me what to use to set lock timeout at database level to avoid deadlocks. If something from the code can be achieved that can be feasible too. 
We use Entity Framework 4

FYI: We have checked profiler, there are no query issues causing deadlock maybe concurrency.

Comment: "We have checked profiler, there are no query issues causing deadlock" - well, clearly that's incorrect!

Comment: @MitchWheat I have limited knowledge about database so apologies if what I am doing is incorrect. I am following few articles on internet. We are getting most deadlocks on one page. I was trying to figure out if there are any update/ insert on that page because from UI its just a search page (so my assumption was to see only select statements). In the profiler I saw few update queries - so I removed them believing all the threads now on this page will only execute select statements which will be fine because of shared locks, However, we are still seeing deadlocks and I have no clue why.

Answer (score 1):

The `@@LOCK_TIMEOUT` is nothing to deal with deadlocks, it [defines only the maximal time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-lock-timeout-transact-sql) which will pass before Microsoft SQL Server attempts to lock some resource and then returns a locking error.
The deadlock situation means that two or more process **already locked** some resources but  *there is a cyclic dependency between two or more threads, or processes, for some set of resources*.

Hence, regardless the value of `@@LOCK_TIMEOUT` the deadlock cannot be prevented in such manner. Please take a look to [Analyze Deadlocks with SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/analyze-deadlocks-with-sql-server-profiler) article.

Comment: thanks for posting an answer. As I was explaining Mitch in the comment above, deadlock in my Application occurs on a page with only select queries. I will go through the link that you have posted. But can two select statements in different processes create a deadlock?

Comment: and one more question. if a table has table lock is there a more chance of getting a deadlock over a row lock?

Comment: @Jay the problem is not in the table lock but 2+ tables/pages/rows locked by2+ transactions in a different order. Check that all transactions lock resources in same order. You need catch deadlock in Profiler and see the concerned resources. Take a look at my simple example ["How to simulate and catch deadlock"](https://www.arbinada.com/en/node/1647)